# Marshal.PtrToStringUni(s) returns class name instead of message

Tags: c#, .net, string, memory-management, marshalling

Im currently trying to get my kernel filter to communicate with my c# application. Kernel app sends a UNICODE_STRING, in my structure, with path to a file. All other variables seem fine and the buffer location seems the same in user and kernel app but when i call my ToString method i get

> usermodeFilter.MinifilterWrapper+NativeMethods+COMMAND_MESSAGE

My c# code looks something like this

```
    private NativeMethods.USERCOMMAND_MESSAGE data = new NativeMethods.USERCOMMAND_MESSAGE();

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Demand)]
    public void FilterGetMessage()
    {

        UInt32 result = NativeMethods.FilterGetMessage(_handle, ref data, (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.USERCOMMAND_MESSAGE)), IntPtr.Zero);
        if (result == NativeMethods.S_OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("message recived");
            Console.WriteLine(this.getProcessNameFromId((int)this.data.cmdMessage.procesID));
            Console.WriteLine(this.data.cmdMessage.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unknown error, number " +result);
        }

    }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public struct COMMAND_MESSAGE { 
            public UInt32 procesID;
            public UNICODE_STRING fileName;
         } 

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct UNICODE_STRING : IDisposable
        {
            public ushort Length;
            public ushort MaximumLength;
            private IntPtr buffer;

            public UNICODE_STRING(string s)
            {
                Length = (ushort)(s.Length * 2);
                MaximumLength = (ushort)(Length + 2);
                buffer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(s);
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Marshal.PtrToStringUni(buffer);
            }
          }
```

C++ part of the code looks

```
            WCHAR parametersKeyBuffer[255];
            gCmdMessageSend.name.Buffer = parametersKeyBuffer;
            gCmdMessageSend.name.MaximumLength = sizeof(parametersKeyBuffer);
            gCmdMessageSend.name.Length = 0;
            RtlCopyUnicodeString(&gCmdMessageSend.name, &fileInfo->Name);
            if (FsClientPort)
                {
                    ulReplayLength = sizeof(gCmdMessageSend);
                    status = FltSendMessage(gFilterHandle, &FsClientPort, &gCmdMessageSend, sizeof(gCmdMessageSend), NULL, &ulReplayLength, &timeout);
                }
```

btw im also getting Invalid access to memory location. error when Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer); so i am guessing im doing something wrong

Comment: You're probably getting the `Invalid access to memory location` error if you're changing where the `buffer` points to. You should only manipulate the buffer in native land not change what it points to.

Comment: im doing something wrong with the buffer, now after `Marshal.PtrToStringUni` i get `Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Console.WriteLine(this.data.cmdMessage.ToString());

You don't have an overwritten `ToString()` method, so it will default to the type name. You need to overwrite the `ToString()` method in this class (`COMMAND_MESSAGE`) as well.